# CoTurn server stopping the media after 600 seconds

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, turn, coturn

I am using the CoTurn server in my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, which I install it from "synaptic" it is working fine for the media communication below 600 seconds but when I Increase the media time to more then 600 seconds up to 600 seconds it is working fine after that it stops transmitting the media.

Is there any configuration needed for that or is there any limitation.

Any suggestion will great help for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

600 seconds is the default value for coTurn server. You need to change **stale-nonce** property in turnserver.conf file. You can check this link https://github.com/coturn/coturn/issues/233 for more info.